# How easy is it to migrate all your 'Google Account' based services to the 'Google Apps For Your Domain' trial

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, migration

Just received the following email:

[image]

I have services such as Reader and Picasa using regular Google Accounts.

Is there an easy way to import them in one step?
Do I have to export from every service on each account and reimport in to the GAFYD services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through this transition. Some stuff is really easy to do - others are hard. Google provides info on how to move things across at their [Help Centre](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/go/fullaccounts), with a [list of what can be migrated and how](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582):

> **Data Transfer**
>
> You can transfer information from one
>   account to another for the following
>   products. For any other product,
>   transferring product information is
>   currently unavailable. This may change
>   over time, so check back here for
>   updates.
>
> AdWords
>   Blogger
>   Bookmarks (Export and import)
>   Contacts (Export and import)
>   FeedBurner
>   iGoogle (To transfer data, create your own backup and restore it to the new account through XML)
>   Maps: Saved Locations
>   Reader
>   YouTube
>
> **Sharing Options**
>
> You can use sharing options with the
>   following products to share data
>   between accounts you own:
>
> Analytics
>   App Engine
>   Calendar
>   Docs (For Google Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, and Forms)
>   Maps: My Maps
>   Picasa
>   Sites

For the 2 you mention...

- Reader - export & import subscriptions works really well, you just lose all your reading statistics etc - this didn't matter to me really.
- Picasa - I changed my logon in the software on my computer and set all my albums to re-sync... laborious, but I'm back up and running. Annoyance: all my photos are now in a different place under a different username. The old one still works though. You'll lose comments & stuff too this way - again, this didn't matter to me as I only had a couple!

Comment: thanks, I have moved my reader subscriptions via an OPML file.

I will still need to phase-out the old account as I have starred items etc.

There doesn't seem to be a better solution to this at the momemnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export starred items from Reader. The most obvious thing to do is bookmark each in your browser. I figured out a workaround, though.

In the old account (with all the starred items) make each starred item a shared item as well (Share link at the bottom of each item).

Log in to your new Reader account. Add the email address for your old account as a followed user. Suddenly your shared items will be visible in your new account! You can proceed to star them for your new account.

This may take a while, depending on how many items you have. I had about 100 items, so I had to share each one in the old account, then star each one in the new.